# Unit in unit area

Tags: forces, pressure, terminology, units

Pressure is defined as force per **unit** area. What is the meaning of **unit** and why is the term **unit** used with area?

Comment: Welcome Nandy to Physics Stack Exchange. It may just be semantic convention, but now you have me wondering why we don't say "unit force per unit area".

Comment: @DavidBailey Perhaps it's because its more convenient to use a 'unit' quantity in denominator than in numerator!

Comment: @Proscionexium But both numerator and denominator have units,  so why refer to one and not the other?  Saying pressure is defined as "force per area" sounds wrong to me, but I can't give a good reason other than linguistic convention.

Comment: @DavidBailey What I meant is not 'units' but 'unity'. When talking about pressure it makes more sense to say 'Force per unit area'. Because 'Unit force per unit area' means Unit pressure. But if you change pressure, you should change only force or area instead of both by same factor. Changing both by same factor will loop back to 'unit pressure'.

Comment: @DavidBailey "Unit force per unit area" is already defined as one Pascal (in SI units), which is just one of the infinite values pressure can take... If you were to redefine Pressure as 1 Pascal, then we'd need a third quantity to specify a different magnitude of what we currently call pressure, say $5N/m²$.

Comment: Thanks @Proscionexium.  I understand your point now and agree that "unit force per unit area" doesn't make sense for the definition since pressure is not always 1 Pascal!

Answer (score 1):

The use of "unit area" means the surface area that the force is being applied to has a value of 1 in whatever unit system you're using (e.g., $1\,\text{cm}^2$ or $1\,\text{m}^2$ or $1\,\text{km}^2$). See, for instance, the [definition provided by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unit): *a determinate quantity (as of length, time, heat, or value) adopted as a standard of measurement*.

When you apply a force to a surface that has an area larger than the unit (e.g., $\alpha\,\text{m}^2$), then the pressure applied by the force $f$ on the unit area is simplified as,
$$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{f\,\text{N}}{\alpha\,\text{m}^2}=\frac{\frac{f}{\alpha}\,\text{N}}{1\,\text{m}^2}$$
So the pressure on the *unit area* is simply the total force scaled by the *total area*.

Answer (score 0):

"Unit" literally means "one." The unit of area is the amount of area that you would represent by the number, 1. It could be one square meter. It could be one square inch or one square foot. Whatever is convenient for you.

For example, if measuring pressure in Pascals meets your needs, then the unit of force is the Newton, and the unit of area is the square meter. If you measure 500 Pascals, that means 500 Newtons of force pressing on every 1 square meter of surface—on every "unit" of surface.